# Databricks: Job having high shuffle write and executing very long

Tags: databricks, fpgrowth

I am having trouble in running a databricks notebook ( scala) , And I see the job is having high write shuffle size. and it already run over an hour. Let's have a look on the following screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCMw2.jpg)

Any idea on checking how why ?

shuffle write: 35.5GB/ 1796240509 
what's the meaning of 35.5GB and 1796240509 ??

Comment: 1796240509 is the number of records whereas Shuffle Write is the sum of all written serialized data on all executors before transmitting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276884/what-is-shuffle-read-shuffle-write-in-apache-spark

Comment: number of what records ???